# Access to war file name from Config.groovy and Datasource.groovy

Tags: grails, war

I want to deploy my war file under several names, just renaming it seems to work fine on tomcat. This obviously then gives me different URLs. I have used request.contextPath to find my own URL within the application while it is running, but if I want e.g. to name the database file after the war file in Datasource.groovy, then there is no request object for me to look at and I am out of luck. How do I do this?

Comment: Does the app create the database file on startup? Is that something you are trying to do?

Comment: Maybe application.properties is something worth looking at?

Comment: @marko I have looked at application.properties but app.name does not reflect either the name of the war file or the subsequent url.

Comment: @aldrin It might create it, or it might use a previously created file. This is only one example, another one is where to put the log files if I want to keep them separate from other wars which are running, and also where searchable should store its compassConnection. For all this stuff I need a name I can derive from the war file name at config time.

Comment: If I'm understanding what you want to do, I'm guessing the best way to do it is change the db-name in Datasource.groovy. Probably not the most elegant solution but it should do the job.

Comment: @marko Thanks for following up but I want to change the war file name and then have everything just work.

Answer (score 0):

How about if you configure separate config files for each deploy using [Externalized configuration](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configExternalized)

Only the values that are different for each deploy need be in these files. Then every time you create a new war, you also create a new config file for this deploy.

(of course you need to manually create it every time, but i figure you could write a script for that or use a find/replace)

Comment: This may be what I end up having to do but ideally I want to be able to change the war file name later and then have everything just work